# Azure DevOps 2019 - Adding Script leads to change of the building agent

Tags: unity-game-engine, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, visual-studio-2022

I have a local building agent for a Unity|HoloLens-Project. Today I had to switch from VS2019 to VS2022 on my building agent and I came across the issue, that the MSBuild-Task-Version of DevOps 2019 is not compatible with VS2022.

So I found a workaround. That workaround is to use the following `script` instead of the `MSBuild` task. But using that `script` I ran into the following misbehavior:

1. If I use the `MSBuild@1`-task my pipeline crashes because of mentioned compatibility problem. But the pipeline uses the right building agent.
2. If I use the `Script` the pipeline crashes because it uses the wrong building agent. That agent has no unity installed and is not mentioned in the YAML.

Yaml:

```
  - task: MSBuild@1
    displayName: 'Build Appx Package - MSBuild@1'
    inputs:
      solution: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)$(unity.outputPath)/*.sln'
      msbuildVersion: 'latest'
      platform: 'ARM64'
      configuration: 'Release'
      msbuildArguments: '/p:AppxBundle=Always /p:AppxPackageDir=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/AppPackages'
  # ----- or ------
  - script: |
      @echo off
      setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
      for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`"!ProgramFiles(x86)!\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe" -latest -products * -requires Microsoft.Component.MSBuild -find MSBuild\**\Bin\MSBuild.exe`) do (set msbuild_exe=%%i)
      "!msbuild_exe!" "$(Build.BinariesDirectory)$(unity.outputPath)/*.sln" /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="ARM64" /p:AppxBundle=Always /p:AppxPackageDir=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/AppPackages /t:rebuild
```

At the beginng of my YAML I set of course the pool and the name of the building agent:

```
- job: unity
  pool:
    name: 'My_Pool'
    demand: Agent.name -equals My_Agent_Unity_1
```

**I don't understand how removing the `MSBuild` task and adding the `script` can cause a different building agent to suddenly be taken.**

Comment: Post your full YAML for both scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand how removing the MSBuild task and adding the script
> can cause a different building agent to suddenly be taken.

Because you entered the wrong keyword "`demand`" in your YAML. It should be `demands`.

```
- job: unity
  pool:
    name: 'My_Pool'
    demands: Agent.name -equals My_Agent_Unity_1
```

Please see [Manually entered demands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#manually-entered-demands) and [pool definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/pool?view=azure-pipelines#pool-name-demands-vmimage) for details.